# Getting time-stamp difference of same user coming multiple times on a website

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have data in BigQuery which have specific columns like time-stamp and userid, Some users visit the website multiple times.

The goal is to find out the time difference of users visiting multiple times.

Even if they visit 14 times, I need to find the difference between every consecutive visit.

This is a sample of my data:

[image]

Comment: I have data of users which are visiting my website with following timestamps as in the image. If in the time span of say 1 minute, a user comes 10 times which means there are 10 timestamps, I need to blacklist that user considering it as robot.

Comment: I tried to sort the timestamps in increasing order and then finding difference of consecutive timestamp if the userid is same but was unable to do that. So looking for a different approach.

Comment: Please add the SQL you tried so far to your question by using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55999372/edit) option

Answer (score 1):

This should help (assuming you want delta in `minute`). You can always switch to whatever period you need (`hour`, `second`, etc.)

Please note the usage of analytical function `LAG` which uses data partitioned over `user_id` and ordered by timestamp `ts`. Also, note that the first appearance of the `user_id` gets the difference of `0` because this is the first time user showed up :). Hope it helps.

```
select user_id, coalesce(timestamp_diff(ts_a, ts_b, minute), 0) as diff_from_prv_visit_minutes from (
  select user_id, ts as ts_a, lag(ts) over (partition by user_id order by ts) as ts_b
  from `mydataset.mytable`
)
```